# Non-universally trivial Chow group of zero-cycles on Fano hypersurfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, chow-groups

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over a field $k$. By (one) definition, the Chow group of zero-cycles $CH_0(X)$ is *universally trivial* if, for every field extension $k \subset K$, the degree map $CH_0(X_K) \rightarrow \mathbf Z$ is an isomorphism.

This idea has been an important ingredient in some major recent advances in birational geometry. In particular, B. Totaro showed ("Hypersurfaces that are not stably rational", available [here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~totaro/papers/public_html/index.html)) that if $X$ is a very general  hypersurface of degree $d$ in $\mathbf  P^{n+1}_\mathbf C$ and $d \geq 2 \lceil (n+2)/3 \rceil$, then $CH_0(X)$ is not universally trivial, and hence $X$ is not stably rational.

Of course, the significant cases are when $X$ is Fano, that is, when $d \leq n+1$. Here $X$ is rationally connected, so $CH_0(X) \cong \mathbf Z$; Totaro's theorem implies that after some base extension $\mathbf C \hookrightarrow F$, the Chow group $CH_0(X_F)$ is bigger than $\mathbf Z$.

**Question:** For $X$ and $d$ as above, what kind of field extension $\mathbf C \hookrightarrow F$ makes $CH_0(X_F)$ bigger than $\mathbf Z$?

Comment: One choice that works is $F = \mathbb{C}(X)$, the function field of $X$.

Comment: Dear @JasonStarr, thanks for your comment. Can you explain why the base-change to that field has bigger Chow group of zero-cycles? And what goes wrong if the degree of $X$ is less than $2n/3$ or so?

Comment: The paper by Totaro is beautiful, and the papers by Koll'ar and Voisin that it builds upon are also beautiful.  You should just read those papers.  For your first question: inside $X\times_{\text{Spec}\ (\mathbb{C})} X$ consider the cycles of the diagonal $\Delta$ and $X\times\{ x_0 \}$ for some $x_0\in X(\mathbb{C})$.  Now restrict on the first factor of $X\times_{\text{Spec}\ \mathbb{C}} X$ to $\text{Spec}\ \mathbb{C}(X)$.  If the pullback $0$-cycles were rationally equivalent, then that would give an *integral* decomposition of the diagonal in $X\times_{\text{Spec}\ \mathbb{C}} X$.

Comment: OK. I will take your advice and read those papers. Thanks again!